# Bash for-loop with input that contains embedded variable

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am trying to write a shell script that uses `wget` to download files in bulk from urls that follow a certain numeric pattern.

Understandably, the url from the user input must contain the variable `$i`.

```
dl.sh http://some/url/$i/some/url 1 9
```

This yields repeated result from the final loop because `$i` will be expanded before passing down into the loop.

```
http://some/url/9/some/url
http://some/url/9/some/url
...
http://some/url/9/some/url
```

Is there a workaround to get this shell script working?

## Source Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# dl.sh url | index_from | index_to

for i in $(seq $2 $3)
do
  echo ${1} # replace with wget for actual download. 
done
```

## Expected Result:

```
http://some/url/1/some/url
http://some/url/2/some/url
http://some/url/3/some/url
...
http://some/url/9/some/url
```

Comment: You are using the script wrong. Define your script as below `#!/bin/bash


for i in $(seq $2 $3)
do
  echo http://some/url/$i
done` and run the script as `bash dl.sh 1 9`

Comment: @Inian: Yes, I know your script will work. My question is: What if I need to use `http://some/url/$i` as part of the user input to the script? Is there a possible workaround for that?

Comment: That is really a bad practice, when you pass `http://some/url/$i`, the `$i` will be expanded by the shell before passed as the argument, which will be empty.

Comment: Leave the `$i` from arg and do `dl.sh http://some/url/ 1 9` and inside the script do `echo $1$i`

Comment: What if `$i` is duplicated? Or embedded somewhere within the url? Eg. `http://some/url/$i/$i` or `http://some/url/$i/some/url`

Comment: In that case I would recommend passing base URL as the first arg, and build up the the other parameters inside

Comment: Could you show me an example?

Comment: Ask it as a separate question which is not a duplicate of the contents above,

Comment: Amended my question. See if it goes.

Comment: Why did you modify the same question? You have totally de-scoped your original question.

Comment: If the value between the URL is dynamic, there is no other way than to split your URL as separate parts. In case of `http://some/url/1/some/url`, pass argument `http://some/url/` as separate and `/some/url` as separate

Comment: Just use a Placeholder in your URL and replace with `sed` like this: `url=$(echo $1 | sed "s/\_IDX\_/$i/g")` and use your script like this: `./dl.sh http://some/url/_IDX_/some/url 1 9`